# How to find if datagridcell have 0 value

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

That piece of code check only first row in datagrid. I need to find all 0 rows in datagrid. I have many models and this need to be called on cellclick to grid than show to another. any help ?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgvNalog.SelectedCells)
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < dgvNalog.RowCount; i++)
        {
            rowIsEmpty = true;
            if (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Kolicina"].Value) == 0)
            {
                rowIsEmpty = false;
                dgvNalog.Rows[i].Cells["Kolicina"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `dataGridView1.Rows` actually have more than 1 row?

Comment: Yes it has about 50 rows

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate each row in `dgvNalog.Rows` collection and check for the zero value like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvNalog.RowCount; i++)
{
    var row = dgvNalog.Rows[i];
    rowIsEmpty = true;
    if (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Kolicina"].Value) == 0)
    {
        rowIsEmpty = false;
        dgvNalog.Rows[i].Cells["Kolicina"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;

        // break; -> comment this to allow other rows to be processed
    }
}
```